# зачем нужен offset в _aligned_offset_malloc

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Подскажите зачем нужен **offset** в `_aligned_offset_malloc` функции? с alignment понятно это значение выравнивания адресов, которое должно быть целой степенью числа 2. Вопрос в том зачем это нужно и в каких случаях используется offset?

Comment: Ну у вас в винде и документация.... -) Судя по [примеру](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=msvc-170) функция `_aligned_offset_malloc(size, alignment, offset)` возвращает такой указатель (p), что (p + offset) должено быть кратно alignment (и не забывайте, что alignment должен быть степенью двойки)